# Error establishing a database connection; how can I determine whether or not these connections are real?

Tags: centos, mysql

I've just run into a problem today with MySQL reaching its database connection capacity.

The error I'm receiving is, `Error establishing a database connection`. When I try to access `/phpma`, I get this error instead: `phpMyAdmin - Error #1040 - Too many connections`.

I've looked up how to change `my.cnf` to increase the number of connections, but I think I've already done this a while back and had no issues since. I'm therefore a little worried that these connections are some kind of vulnerability.

I'm running CentOS. Is there any easy way of checking these connections? Is there anything I should be looking out for, or maybe just a way of culling connections that have been active too long (does MySQL even work this way?).

Answer (score 2):

To see the which threads are running in mysql, from Linux:

```
root@myserver:~> mysqladmin processlist
```

The equivalent mysql query to that would be:

```
root@myserver:~> mysql
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G
```

Also, check out [Examining Thread Information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/thread-information.html) to see what the output means.  Most notably:

> **Command** and **State** indicate what the thread is doing.
>
> Most states correspond to very quick operations. If a thread stays in
>   a given state for many seconds, there might be a problem that needs to
>   be investigated.

The main point is to look at the mysql process list and see if anything looks suspicious to you, given the nature of your environment, e.g. long-running processes or large # of processes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command and list out running mysql apps,

```
ps -aux | grep 'mysql'
```

then, start your required mysql in its default port "3306"